# JUnit - testing with re-usable functions; validity

Tags: java, junit

What I am trying to do is to test some Lucene code I wrote and would like some information on best practices when using JUnit for testing. Lucene, BTW, is a search engine which you can use to create a flat file to index a bunch of data.

So what I would like to test is the creation of this inverted index, then search through the index to verify that some data is present.

My question is in the code:

```
public class IndexTest {

    @Test
    public void testWriteIndexFromDB() {
        //run test
        assertTrue(something in this test); // some test for this method    
        // Is using a function like so a proper way of writing a test? 
        checkSomeDataIsReturned(); 
    }

    @Test
    public void testWriteIndexFromExcelFile() {
        //run test
        assertTrue(something in this test); // some test for this method    
        // Is using a function like so a proper way of writing a test? 
        checkSomeDataIsReturned(); 
    }

    @Test
    public void testRefreshIndexWithNewData() {
        //run test
        assertTrue(something in this test); // some test for this method    
        // Is using a function like so a proper way of writing a test? 
        checkSomeDataIsReturned(); 
    }

    // this function checks that data is returned after writing an index 
    public void checkSomeDataIsReturned(){  // not a test but does a check anyways
         results = myIndex.searchForStuff(some input);
         assertTrue(results.length > 0); // if length is zero, there is no data and something went wrong 
    }
}
```

To summarize, I have three options to write an index, I am testing that each of them writes. Is the re-usable function that is not a test the proper way to write a test? Or is there a better practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is off course a good thing write reusable code in test, but more important than that is writing that are easy to understand. In general the asserts are in the test method itself, moving the asserts to helpers methods can make your test difficult to understand.

One way to write reusable code for checking expectations its using Hamcrest (https://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/wiki/Tutorial) and build a matchers (the library also comes with some very useful matchers for collections and stuff like that).

for example, you can write something like that:

```
public void
test_can_index_from_database() {
    // create your index from database

    assertThat(myIndex, containsWord('expected_word_in_index'));
}
```

The matchers "containsWord(String)" its a matcher that you write using hamcrest and you can re-use this logic in all your test. And with hamcrest you can write really easy to understand test.

Comment: Thanks for recommending Hamcrest, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, good practices such as reusable code are to be used in unit tests, too.

However, please consider that if you are in need to repeat code in unit tests, it *may* (and often does) mean that your tested methods take too many responsibilities.

I don't know if it *really* is your case but think about refactoring your code (here splitting your tested methods into more smaller methods) so you don't feel the need to repeat the same tests all over.

When each method takes a single responsibility only, and delegate the shared code to another method/class, you test this functionality somewhere else and here just test (using mocking and spying) if your methods calls the corresponding method/object.